# [UNIX]Sending large file socket stream in c

Tags: c, file, sockets, unix, client-server

I've created a Client in C that essentially sends the content of a file and a number of line to remove to the Server. The server creates a child that reads the content and then send it right back to the Client, except for the line received. The communication is made with a socket stream, and the content of the file is sent char-for-char. The problem appears when the client send a file bigger than 9.9Mb, the server reads the contents of the file but at some point it stops, and the only way for closing the server is by killing the process with CTRL-C.
This is the code of the child of the server:

```
if (fork() == 0){ 
        close(listen_sd);
        host = gethostbyaddr((char *)&client_addr.sin_addr, sizeof(client_addr.sin_addr), AF_INET);
        if (host == NULL) {
            printf("Server (figlio %d): client host non trovato.\n", getpid());
        
            exit(8);
        }
        else 
            printf("Server (figlio %d): operazione richiesta da %s.\n", getpid(), host->h_name);
    
        host = gethostbyaddr((char *)&client_addr.sin_addr, sizeof(client_addr.sin_addr), AF_INET);
        
        if ((read(conn_sd, &sub_line, 1) > 0))
            printf("Server (figlio %d): eliminazione della linea %d...\n", getpid(), sub_line);


        line = 1;
        while((nread = read(conn_sd, &c, sizeof(char))) != 0) {
            if (nread < 0){
                printf("Server (figlio %d): impossibile leggere il file.\n", getpid(), sub_line); 
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            
            if(line != sub_line)
                write(conn_sd, &c, 1);
                
            if(c == '\n')
                line += 1;
        }

        close(conn_sd);
        
        exit(0);

    }
```

And this is the code of the client that sends the content of the file, reads the result and then write it on a file:

```
#define DIM_BUFF 256
[...]
write(sd, &line, sizeof(int));
        
        char buff[DIM_BUFF];
        while ((nread = read(fd_sorg, buff, DIM_BUFF)) > 0)
            write(sd, buff, nread);
        shutdown(sd, 1);
        
        while ((nread = read(sd, buff, DIM_BUFF)) > 0){
            write(fd_dest, buff, nread);
        }
```

Comment: What is the server doing when it "stops"?

Comment: Use a debugger. It will tell you instantly where the server is "stuck",

Comment: The server stops in the read/write cycle, I tried without the write function just to count the file lines and it works, so I guess is the write function that is stalling the server

Comment: The client writes an sizeof(int) for the line but the server reads one byte with : read(conn_sd, &sub_line, 1)

Comment: Not sure why you need to call shutdown() on the socket. But why do use a hardcoded "1" value instead of the defined enum for it : SHUT_WR ?

Comment: I fixed the sizeof(int) on the server side, but the problem still remains